# Drawing stripes in a flag math formula

Tags: android, math, rectangles

I have a rectangle with known size and position. (flag)
I have to fill this rectangle with 4 other rectangles. (stripes)
Each stripe must have 1/4 of the total width of the flag and his position is near the previous.
I have to draw this stripes with a random angle that goes from 0° to 90°.
0° = Vertical stripes (stripe width = flag width / 4)
90° = Horizontal stripes (stripe width = flag height / 4)

How can I calculate the width of each stripe for other angles?

```
int stripes = 4;
RectF rect = new RectF(0, 0, 100f, 75f);
float angle = new Random.nextInt(90);
float stripeSize;
if (angle == 0) {
    stripeSize = rect.width() / stripes;
} else if (angle == 90) {
    stripeSize = rect.height() / stripes;
} else {
    stripeSize = ?
}

canvas.save();
canvas.rotate(angle, rect.centerX(), rect.centerY());

float offset = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < stripes; i++) {
    if (angle == 0) {
        reusableRect.set(offset, rect.top, offset + stripeSize, rect.bottom);
    } else if (angle == 90) {
        reusableRect.set(rect.left, offset, rect.right, offset + stripeSize);
    } else {
        reusableRect.set(?, ?, ?, ?);
    }
    canvas.drawRect(reusableRect, paint);

    offset += stripeSize;
}

canvas.restore();
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's pretend you have one stripe. Depending on the angle, the stripe width is going to be a value between the shorter dimension (the height in your case) and the longer dimension (the width in your case). The formula for the stripe width calculation should look something like this:

```
height + ((width - height) * ?)
```

where ? varies between 0 and 1 based on the angle of rotation. To me that sounds like the sine function might be a good candidate: sine(0) = 0 and sine(90) = 1. You can use `Math.sin()`, but be aware that the argument it takes is in radians, not degrees, so you need to use `Math.toRadians()` on your angle first. Then just divide by the number of stripes:

```
double radians = Math.toRadians(angle);
float stripeTotal = height + ((width - height) * Math.sin(radians));
float stripeWidth = stripeTotal / 4; // or however many stripes you have
```

If it's not perfect, you can adjust the formula. One last point, since these values only need to be calculated once, I would do that separately every time the angle changes (if it ever changes), not inside of `onDraw()`.

Comment: I tried it and it helped to adjust some things. But it still works only at 0° and 90°. I am trying to start over with a square and at 45° the stripeTotal should be long as the Hypotenuse so the formula is not correct. Now I have to position of the stripes since I start drawing from the left to the right and I think I should start from the center

Comment: You are right, my formula doesn't quite work. The total stripe width can be as much as the diagonal of the rectangle. You should be able to find out what angle would make the diagonal the total stripe width and come up with a better formula.

Comment: Yes infact, i am moving on line intersection algorithm. Draw a line from the top-left point of the rectangle, with the "angle". Then I find the second intersection point and finally I can calculate the max length.